# 2D Sprite Physics regarding movement

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, game-physics

I'm trying to implement 2D physics into an asteroids type game.  I have collision boundaries set up at the window borders.

However, when I collide my ship sprite into a boundary (and reverse the proper velocity for either the x or y axis), I occasionally get a glitch when I go to move. The ship will jump temporarily, but if I hold the move key long enough it will usually fix itself.

The problem is that this glitch is noticeable.

Relevant code sections:

```
#update velocity
def velocity(self, speed):
    self.vx += math.sin(math.radians(self.angle)) * speed
    self.vy += math.cos(math.radians(self.angle)) * speed

    magnitude = math.sqrt(self.vx*self.vx + self.vy*self.vy)
    if magnitude > self.maxvel:
        self.vx *= 4/magnitude
        self.vy *= 4/magnitude
    if self.speed >= self.maxvel:
        self.speed = self.maxvel
    if self.speed <= -self.maxvel:
        self.speed = -self.maxvel
```

My movement code:

```
if (key[K_UP]):
    newShip.speed += 1
    newShip.moving = 1

if (key[K_DOWN]):
    newShip.speed -= 1
    newShip.moving = 1

if (key[K_LEFT]):
    newShip.angle += 4

if (key[K_RIGHT]):
    newShip.angle -= 4
```

My full code is here: http://pastebin.com/19rHq97R To run there are only 2 images required, you can really use anything I guess.

I think the problem has something to do with the reversal of the x or y velocity on detection of a collision, but I can't nail the exact problem. Any insight is appreciated.

EDIT: I did some more investigation. I wonder if the sudden jumps are because I don't have any sort of acceleration programmed in. http://pastebin.com/vFy9tjyN excerpt from my terminal log. I print out relevant variables from my program.

Comment: Are you using a fixed-timestep? Otherwise timestep jumps might be causing the instability. Meaning if it penetrates a boundry, it might move 800 units, while next frame it only moves 600. Making it collide after already being inside. So swapping causes it to stay stuck and bounce.

Comment: @monkey I'm not even taking the timestep into account yet. I'm not entirely convinced it has to do with the collision itself, since the ship can collide, travel for some time, and then when 'thrust' is applied, the problem still presents itself.

Comment: Might be unrelated, but cos is for x, and sine is for y.

Comment: I would recommend adding logging that spits out the ship location, direction and velocities. Do this once per frame/update. Then you'll need to determine the frame/update where the new values are not what you expect them to be. Right now, just looking at the code and finding what's "wrong" is very difficult without some data to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DirDict = {"left": (-speed, 0), "right": (speed, 0), "up": (0, -speed), "left": (0, speed)}

if w:
    Direction = DirDict["left"]
```

I think this will be more stable; it's always worked for me.